# Ring Doorbell w/ Digital Chime

Tags: electrical, wiring, transformer, doorbell

I purchased a ring doorbell 2 for my sister for Christmas. I am pretty tech savvy and offered to install it for her last night. I went through the instructions several times but I was not able to get it working correctly.

She has a digital chime that is about a 5 second sound of the "Big Ben" clock. Due to this, I followed the instructions of using the included diode. No matter which combination of the two wires and the orientation of the diode, as soon as the power was turned on at the breaker, the chime inside the house would continuously go off. It didn't seem to make it through the full chime before it kept looping and starting over which made me think it was a power issue.

I tried both with and without the diode as I am certain it is not a mechanical doorbell and was not successful.

The wiring used in her home for the doorbell is a cat5/6 cable and only two of the wires are hooked up to the doorbell, the others are cut back to the edge of the casing.

I asked her to take a look in the garage for the transformer to send me some pictures but she claims she couldn't find it (would a digital chime use one?).

Anyway, I am lost on what direction to go with this now. She likes the existing indoor chime and I don't want to have to buy one of the Ring door chimes to fix this issue.

**Questions:**

1. Could the doorbell not be getting enough power as it is only going
   over a low voltage cat5/6 cable?
2. If the power is the problem, can the transformer be upgraded and if so, how does that impact the existing chime? Wouldn't that then receive too much power?
3. Anything else I can look at to try and resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the specific chime, down the the model, was not supported by Ring. It was one that included a transformer and the chime itself. I had to remove that and put in my own transformer and mechanical chime to get it all working. As soon as I did this, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the digital chime may be to sensitive for the ring, most of the digital chimes I have installed used the existing transformer and required led switches if illumination was wanted at the switch. I would contact the MFG because it sounds like you tried the correct wiring I doubt there is anything wrong with the transformer with the only possibility that it is two small I think the ring takes ~30va.
There is a list on line of incompatible digital chimes almost 20 brands so it probably the chime itself not your wiring or the transformer.